# GraphQL/C# accept-header, json response issue

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-core, graphql

Issue:
I am hitting an api using postman with/without accept-header value, I am getting a string response during debugging with backlash inside it, but the response is in json format in postman. Is this behavior something to deal with graphql/.netcore/httprequests?

Sample Request and its Headers:

https://localhost:5006/api/graphql

Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,br
Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json
Connection:keep-alive
Body has necessary query parameters as well.

Comment: According to your description, I still couldn't understand your question clearly. Do you mean you want to know why the graphql always return the json format response?

Comment: Yeah, during debugging the response is string format but in postman it shows in json format and content-type of response is shown as text/plain